# How to add new records to last row of a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my gridview I have  a primary key column. The newly inserted rows are inserting according to the descending order of this primary key defaultly. How can I avoid this? And I want to display newly inserted records to the last row of gridview. My code is here

```
   SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select_string, con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        con.Close();


        foreach (GridViewRow grv in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (grv.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (grv.RowIndex > lastRowIndex)
                {
                    lastRowIndex = grv.RowIndex;
                }
            }
        }
        lastRowIndex = GridView2.Rows.Count - 1;
        GridView2.Rows[lastRowIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your design: make `AllowSorting="false"`
and it will insert at the last row automatically